# Android app with ssh-copy-id ability

Tags: ssh, android, ssh-keys

As the titles says, I would like to copy my ssh key to the server and afterwards disable root password login for security reasons.

I'm using JuiceSSH but it seems to lack ssh-copy-id for the free version anyway.

Any apps that support this command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any apps that support ssh-copy-id but connectbot makes this pretty easy without it.

APP: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.woltage.irssiconnectbot&hl=en

What you can do with connectbot is in the main menu select 'manage pubkeys'.  In that screen, you can generate a new key.  Once you've generated it, you can press and hold that key and select 'copy public key' in the menu and connect to the server and simply paste that line in the server's .ssh/authorized_keys.  Once you have a key generated you can do this pretty easily for many hosts.

I realize this isn't a direct answer to your question but it is an alternative to a paid version of Juice.

Comment: You are correct. JuiceSSH runs "scripts" for pro users so yea.

Answer (score 1):

The free version of JuiceSSH does support copying a key to the clipboard, similar to connectbot.  Long press on chosen identity, then select *Export Public Key*. *Copy to Clipboard* should be one of the sharing choices.

PS, I would have preferred to comment but I don't have the points.